# Is there a Vim plugin that would TAB-complete symbols from CTags index?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, vim-plugin, code-completion, mc

I've stumbled upon a quite innovative functionality in editor – ability to TAB-complete symbols from CTags index, on this Asciinema [video](https://asciinema.org/a/cp4I3tFfKrLNS9SME7XE2w6Nk).

I wonder if there is anything like it available for Vim? I've been using many completion engines like eg. CoC, however none of them seems to offer what NeoMCEdit does. Is there such plugin for Vim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic keyword completion, `:help i_ctrl-p`/`:help i_ctrl-n`, already does that out of the box because of the default value of `:help 'complete'`.

Alternatively, you can use your `tags` files as exclusive source with `:help i_ctrl-x_ctrl-]`.